# WAMP server on WIndows 10 installation problems

Tags: mysql, windows, wamp

On my new 64 bits Windows 10 system I'm trying to get WAMP server running. However, no such luck.

```
[05-Apr-2016 08:43:34 UTC] PHP Warning:  chmod(): Permission denied in C:\wamp\scripts\config.inc.php on line 68
[05-Apr-2016 08:43:34 UTC] Impossible to modify the file C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts to be writable
[05-Apr-2016 08:43:34 UTC] The file C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts is not writable
```

I instructed Windows to not startup IIS, and instructed my anti virus software to not lock hosts. Both did not resolve my problem. What other options do I have?

Comment: Could you please try to run wamp as administrator ?

Comment: And try to read troubleshooting with this link http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,137195,137195

Comment: That did (half) the trick. "1 of 2 services running". When I go to http://localhost/ I see "IIS Windows" as title of the webpage, and not Apache page. I then stopped the IIS webserver (net stop WAS, as administrator) and restarted the all services. Now I have a green WAMP icon. Thanks.

Comment: @androidnation Thanks for the troubleshooting guide (forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,137195,137195). Pity it is so hard to find (with a search engine). Installing it as root sure solved a lot of problems.

Comment: Do you still have some errors ?

Comment: @androidnation No. I'm fine now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to provide Admin Privileges to WAMP Server during installation as well as during launch.Its important to Install with the **"Run as administrator"** option. Also change write access in folder

> C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\host

.